# How high is an acceptable framerate for animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a snow animation with javascript. With a framerate of 200ms it looks ok but is not 100% fluid. The following example uses 20ms is that ok, or totally inefficient and a waste of CPU?

```
window.setInterval(snow.draw, 20);
```

[example](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?CJwIdqnK)

```
snow = {
count: 60,
delay: 20,
flutter: 0.2,
wind: 1.0,
w1: 1,
minSpeed: 0.3,
maxSpeed: 4,
cv: null,
flakes: [],
toggle: function() {
    if(window.snowtimer)
        snow.stop();
    else
        snow.start();
},
resize: function() {
    snow.cv.width = innerWidth;
    snow.cv.height = innerHeight;
    snow.gt = snow.ct.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,snow.cv.height);
    snow.gt.addColorStop(0.0, '#6666ff');
    snow.gt.addColorStop(1.0, '#ffffff');
    snow.ct.fillStyle = snow.gt;
},
start: function() {
    snow.cv = document.createElement('canvas');
    snow.cv.width = snow.cv.height = 10; // set initial size
    snow.cv.id = 'backgroundSnowCanvas';
    document.body.appendChild(snow.cv);
    snow.createFlake();
    snow.ct = snow.cv.getContext('2d'),
    snow.cv.style.position = 'absolute';
    snow.cv.style.top = 0;
    snow.cv.style.left = 0;
    snow.cv.style.zIndex = -1;
    snow.resize();
    var c = snow.count;
    snow.flakes = [];
    do {
        snow.flakes.push(new snow.flake());
    } while(--c);
    snow.ct.fillRect(0,0,snow.cv.width,snow.cv.height);
    window.snowtimer = window.setInterval(snow.draw, snow.delay);
    window.addEventListener('resize',snow.resize);
},
stop: function() {
    window.clearInterval(window.snowtimer);
    var c = document.getElementById('backgroundSnowCanvas');
    c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
    window.snowtimer=snow=null;
},
draw: function() {
    var ct = snow.ct, f = snow.flakes, c = snow.count;
    ct.fillRect(0,0,snow.cv.width,snow.cv.height);

    do {
        if(f[--c].draw(ct) && ++fdone) { };
    } while(c);
    snow.wind += Math.cos(snow.w1++ / 180.0);
},
flake: function() {
    this.draw = function(ct) {
        ct.drawImage(snow.flakeImage,this.x + snow.wind,this.y,this.sz,this.sz);
        this.animate();
    };
    this.animate = function() {
        this.y += this.speed;
        this.x += this.flutter * Math.cos(snow.flutter * snow.flutter * this.y);
        if(this.y > innerHeight)
            this.init(1);
    };
    this.init = function(f) {
        this.speed = snow.minSpeed + (Math.random() * (snow.maxSpeed - snow.minSpeed));
        this.sz = ~~(Math.random() * 40) + 20;
        this.flutter = ~~(Math.random() * snow.flutter * (60-this.sz));
        this.x = (Math.random() * (innerWidth + this.sz)) - this.sz;
        this.y = f ? -this.sz : Math.random() * innerHeight;
    };
    this.init();
},
createFlake: function() {
    snow.flakeImage = document.createElement('canvas');
    snow.flakeImage.width = snow.flakeImage.height = 40;
    var c = snow.flakeImage.getContext('2d');
    c.fillStyle = '#fff';
    c.translate(20,20);
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(-5,-20,10,40);
    c.rotate(Math.PI / 3.0);
    c.rect(-5,-20,10,40);
    c.rotate(Math.PI / 3.0);
    c.rect(-5,-20,10,40);
    c.closePath();
    c.fill();
},
```

};

Comment: I think 30 frames per second is reasonable. Traditional film stock runs at about 24fps. Most modern video games are around 30fps (60 with higher end graphics cards).

Comment: 1000 / 20 = 50 fps. 50 is pretty good, but I would use 16 ms delay for 60 fps. That's the native fps for most displays.

Comment: window.setInterval(snow.draw, 20);

Comment: Off topic, interesting speed test: http://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/56

Comment: Is this post an opinion question?

Comment: The human eye actually processes around 20 frames per second, up to 60 when survival instincts or panic kick in.

Comment: @ohmusama It's close, but I'd say this is more of a _standards_ question. I don't think OP is asking us what we think the best frame rate should be, but rather how high of a frame rate he/she should go before the animation begins wasting resources and the effects of the higher rate are lost...

Comment: If you are targeting modern browsers you should look into [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: And make sure you read up on Paul Irish/Addy Osmani's blog posts on repainting and performance. There was one recently that might help get you that extra umph you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20ms is too fast. 50FPS is too much for snow effects. **20fps** is the typical eye but **25fps**, if you want to save on processing.

**30FPS** or higher for good quality.

Final answer: you should set it to **30ms**. Its not a waste if you want the graphic to render close to the fastest human eye. Try it at 40ms (25fps), if you like it will save you on processes and not compromise the visual effect.

Answer (score 1):

I think 30 frames per second is reasonable. Traditional film stock runs at about 24fps. Most modern video games are around 30fps (60 with higher end graphics cards).

The human eye actually processes around 20 frames per second on average, up to 60 when survival instincts or panic kick in.

1000/30ms is a little more than 30fps.

Comment: Film can get away with 24FPS it because it introduces motion blur, giving the appearance of a higher framerate.

Comment: The number of "visually processed" frames per second should *not* be confused with the FPS required for visually smooth animation. Movies - at 24fps - *aren't* visually smooth (and it drives my friend nuts when watching normally-unsmooth movies on motion-smoothing devices).

Comment: @Bubby4j That is correct, and panning at 24fps is very blurry, but I think for an animation, anything higher than 30fps is just overkill and using more processing than required. If you can hit 60fps without any issues then more power to you.

Answer (score 1):

The average human can see 24-30 fps. 15 fps is typical in web animation. High quality movies use about 30 fps. High quality tv animation is around 24 fps.

So

```
window.setInterval(snow.draw,your choice);
```

There are a bunch if dependent functions so you may want to play around with your fps using the industry standards as your average and not deviating to greatly. 24 fps looks pretty good to me.

However, you could also use a multiple refresh rate like 48 fps, repeating frames 2 times, if you are displeased.

Still, the amount of processing that goes on can make a huge difference in a web browser where resources can vary greatly. In the old days, a few years ago, this could have a huge effect on how fluid anything was including animation. Its good to be as minimal as possible. Could you combine anything?

[Wikipedia has a good article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate) on frame rates and states the following.

```
The human eye and its brain interface, the human visual system, can process 10 to 12 separate images per second, perceiving them individually.
```

and
     Film and video makers use 24p even if their productions are not going to be transferred to film, simply because of the on-screen "look" of the (low) frame rate which matches native film.

Here is some information [on animation fps.](http://animation.about.com/od/faqs/f/faq_fpsnumber.htm)

Answer (score 0):

One of the key things for an animation to look "smooth" is that the framerate is *constant*.  For a computer, that means the framerate needs to be an even divisor of the monitor framerate: for the 60Hz monitors in common use these days, that means 60FPS, 30FPS, 15FPS, etc.

Most people can perceive the individual frames of a 15FPS framerate, and some people can perceive 30FPS.  I'd go for 60FPS (16ms) if your program can manage to draw that fast (especially if it involves fast motion), and 30FPS (33ms) if it can't.